# How to get slash (/) using request.args.get() in Flask?

Tags: flask

How to get `/` using request.args.get().
When I send a text containing slash (/) API throws 502 Bad Gateway Error, otherwise it works as expected.

For example when I request `/urls/?query=abcd` it works fine, but when I request `/urls/?query=abc/d` API returns with 502 Bad Gateway Error

```
@app.route('/urls/')
def gl():
    query  = request.args.get('query', None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is one of those characters that must be "URL encoded" (as `%2F`). In this case, you'd request

```
/urls/?query=abc%2Fb
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for details, and note the RFC 3986 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Or declare a **path** argument in your route like this:

```
@app.route('/urls/<path:query>')
```

Thus, `/urls/query/abc/d` should return `abc/d` into query

---

(*path: Like string but accepts slashes.*)

Comment: I want to get two arguments from url and more important I want to keep the url format as it is `/urls/?query=`